# process lines of a huge text file

Tags: linux, text-processing

I have a huge text file containing lines with the following format:

```
var1 val1 var2 val2 var3 val3
.
.
.
var1 val1' var2 val2' var3 val3'
. 
.
.
var1 val1'' var2 val2'' var3 val3''
```

How can I compare the values of var3 with a specific number (for example 1000 ) to keep the the text file from beginning to the line in which val3=1000 and delete the remaining lines (from that specific line to the end)? Any sed, awk or tail command?

Answer (score 1):

[sed](/questions/tagged/sed) can do this task pretty well. By default [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) prints each line, so I try to match a line with your pattern and quits when succeeds, that avoids to print the rest of the file.

```
sed '/var3[ ]\+1000\([ ]\|$\)/ { q }' infile
```

**EDIT**: I've added `([ ]\|$\)` after the number to avoid a digit that starts with `1000`.

Comment: stops printing at var3= 100008!!!

Comment: Prints the whole file to the end!

Answer (score 1):

Awk solution:

```
awk '{print} /var3 1000 / {exit}' INPUTFILE
```

Comment: This one also stops printing at var3= 100008!!!

Comment: @user2517676 you are right, corrected, thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 1):

assuming your file is sorted according the field var3 and you need all the lines till the value is greater than 1000:

```
awk '{if(!($5<=1000))exit}1' your_file
```

Incase your file is not sorted, and you need the lines where var3 is less than or equal to 1000 then:

```
awk '$5>=1000' your_file
```

Comment: The file is sorted, however, the the values of val3 are not necessarily consecutive numbers. they can be like this 3-5-8-11-12-... The other point is that the file consists of different lines which each one has its own format. I wanna just process some of those lines which have the mentioned format.